# Hive regex_extract for values in bracket

Tags: sql, regex, hive, extract

This is probably a simple problem but unfortunately I wasn't able to get the results I wanted.

I have the following input line

```
A[C1234/3/4]b[123/0]C[123/0]d[123/0]E[123/0]d[http://google.com]AD[M/1/2]g[ab]
```

I want to retrieve the numbers using regex_extract in Hive

```
 1/2
```

which is followed by "AD[M/ " in each case.

I am currently using

```
      '\(AD([^)]+)\)' which gives output  AD[M/1/2]g[ab]
```

Implementing any other like  (//d*) is give a code 2 error. Please suggest the possible replacements

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
.*AD\[M\/(.*)\].*
```

by the way `()` should be the capturing bracket pair, not `\(\)`

Comment: This also returns the code 2 error i.e the  regexp_extract function failing while using some of the regex.